# My prefix is a past introduction

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix is a past introduction,
>
> my infix is a luminous motion production.
>
> My suffix is a little man without his silence,
>
> overall, I help artists find balance.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Metronome

My prefix is a past introduction,

> **Met** is the past tense of meet

my infix is a luminous motion production.

> [**Tron**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron) is a movie which could be described as luminous.

My suffix is a little man without his silence,

> **Nome** is Gnome without the silent 'G'.

overall, I help artists find balance.

> A **metronome** allows musicians to keep in time.

Comment: Correct! Way to go.

Comment: Great answer, hexomino! I totally missed on the meaning of "past introduction"...here I was trying to force fit "ahoy" or something as the prefix...